# Node.js - How to embed a PDF file inputted by user on a mobile device without needing Flash?

Tags: node.js, pdf, embed, filereader

I'm developing a web application where the user can send pictures of their personal documents. These documents can be sent either as images or PDF files, and I'm reading and displaying a preview of them using an **embed tag** and with the help of **FileReader's ReadAsDataURL** method.

Here is the code:

```
  var oFReader = new FileReader();
  oFReader.readAsDataURL($("#input-id")[0].files[0]);

  oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
       $('#embed-tag-id').attr('src', oFREvent.target.result); //base64 string
       $('#embed-tag-id').attr('type', mimeType); // mimeType
  };
```

If the user sends an image, the preview works perfectly on both mobile devices and desktop computers, no problems there.

However, if the document sent is a PDF file the preview does not work on mobile devices.. I believe that is due to Flash, which is not installed by default on these devices.

I've tried using `<object>` as well as `<iframe>` and none of them worked either

I thought about using something like Google Docs Viewer but I'd need to upload that image somewhere, which is not the intention considering that the user is only previewing the file inputted, and not actually sending it to the application just yet.

I'd like to solve this while still using `<embed>` because it works simply for images and PDFs, but if that's not possible I'd be happy to try a different solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I believe that is due to Flash, which is not installed by default on these devices.

No, it has nothing to do with Flash, it has to do with lack of an embeddable PDF reader.

> If the user sends an image, the preview works perfectly on both mobile devices and desktop computers, no problems there.

There are probably some desktops it isn't working on either.

`<embed>` is problematic.  It's effectively a way to embed content that is rendered by plugins rather than the browser itself.  Sometimes these are handled by the browser, such as in the case of Flash in Chrome, and probably  your images.

You're going to have to either render that PDF to a Canvas or SVG with JavaScript, or you'll have to upload it (at least, in-part) to a server to get a preview image.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is indeed something to do with Flash, because if I try to use the browser mobile device simulator when I upload the PDF, I get the message "Flash was disabled" on the toolbar and I can't enable it manually. When I open it on desktop, however, this message does not appear.